# i don't succeed to align verticaly the text inside <a> tag

Tags: css, flexbox

i can't align verticaly the text inside the a tag [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcTa3.png).

```css
navigation-item__link {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<a class="navigation-item__link" href="/auth">Login</a>
```

also tried with,

```css
vertical-align: middle;
```

but it also didn't work.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61374450/10634638

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for basic button **no need** to use flexbox.

For **horizontally align** change the display from `display: inline` (default value) to display `block` and add text-align center.

```css
a{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<a class="navigation-item__link" href="/auth">Login</a>
```

Sometimes you want to align `inline-block` buttons - the most simple way to do this is by extra `text-align:center` wrapper.

```css
a{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: lightgray;
  line-height: 1;
  
}

.align-center{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="align-center">
   <a class="navigation-item__link" href="/auth">Log in</a>
   <a class="navigation-item__link" href="/auth">Sing up</a>
   <br><br>
   <a style="display: block;" class="navigation-item__link" href="/auth">Back</a>
 </div>
```

For **V-align** - use padding-top/bottom (Easier to manage space like this and not by flexbox or height/min-height):
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp

```css
a{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<a class="navigation-item__link" href="/auth">Login</a>
```

If you want to align the button to some "card" flexbox is very useful.

```css
a{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}

.flex-align-v-h{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-align-v-h">
  <div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <a class="navigation-item__link" href="/auth">Login</a> 
  </div>
</section>
```

If the text does not align to the button inspect element (Maybe your styles inherit extra top/bottom margin/padding).

Answer (score 0):

Look at my sample code, i hope you can understand and please provide necessary code.

UPDATE: wrap your `a` tag with a `div` and give flex properties to that div.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="/auth">Login</a>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried to do it its just not working for some reason. also i edited the question

Comment: @gdsdasgga you want to "Login" in center vertically ?

Comment: yes. its not exactly in the center. i realy dont know why, the flex thing should have worked

Comment: uh didn't know that, do you have an idea what will work here?

Comment: What about adding more padding bottom .wrapper{padding-bottom:7px} or reduce line height .wrapper{line-height:15pix;}

Comment: I tried also to wrap with div and gave it flex properties but it also didnt work

Comment: i can easly fix that with padding but i think its kinda ugly, im looking for something more elegent, maybe there is no other solution and thats what should do.

Answer (score 0):

As Robin says you must place your  inside a div and assign those properties and height and width to the parent, the Robin answer doesn't have a height for that reason you can't see it centered

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="/auth">Login</a>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="/auth">Login</a>
</div>
```

Comment: its also not working, gave it height of 100%.
its still not centered inside the a tag.